# Interaction of multiple overlapping instances

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, overlapping-instances

The module `Type.hs` defines the homonym `newtype` and exports only its type constructor, but not the value constructor, to avoid exposing the detail; it also provides a constructor function `makeType` to balance the lack of value ctor. Why do I need to wrap a `String` in a new type? Because I want it to be more than a `String`; in my specific case, `Type` is actually called `Line`, and what corresponds to `makeType` enforces that it contains only one `\n`, as the last character. A `newtype` seemed the most obvious choice to me. If this is not the case, forgive me: I'm learning.

```hs
module Type (Type, makeType) where

newtype Type = Type String

makeType :: String -> Type
makeType = Type
```

In order to show a value of type `Type` the way I like (for instance, given my actual usecase of `Line`, I might want to represent `\n` with a nice unicode character, or with the sequence `<NL>`, or whatever), I created another module `TypeShow.hs`, which I *later* (in the attempt of doing what I'm describing) I edited by adding some pragmas. Why another module? Because I guess the way something works inside and the way I show it to screen are two separete aspects. Am I wrong?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module TypeShow () where

import Type

instance Show Type where
  show = const "Type"

-- the following instance came later, see below why
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Show (Maybe Type) where
  show (Just t) = show t
  show _ = ""
```

Beside this pair of modules (which describe the core of `Type`, and how it should be shown), I created other similar pairs `Type1`/`Type1Show`, `Type2`/`Type2Show`, which all wrap a `String` to represent and show other `String`-like entities.

For other reasons, I also needed another type which wraps an optional value, which can be of type `Type`, `Type1`, or any other type, so I wrote this module

```hs
module Wrapper (Wrapper, makeWrapper, getInside) where

newtype Wrapper a = Wrapper { getInside :: Maybe a }

makeWrapper :: a -> Wrapper a
makeWrapper = Wrapper . Just
```

(In reality `Wrapper` actually wraps more than one `Type` value, but I'll avoid putting more details then necessary; if the following is stupid exactly because I'm wrapping only one `Type` value in `Wrapper`, then please consider it's wrapping more than one, in reality.) Again, here I tried to hide the details of `Wrapper` while providing `makeWrapper` to make one, and `getInside` to have a "controlled" access to its inside.

I also wanted to show this on screen, so I created a corresponding `WrapperShow.hs` module, so that `Wrapper`'s `show` method relies on the content's `show` method.

```hs
module WrapperShow () where

import Wrapper

instance Show a => Show (Wrapper a) where
  show = show . getInside
```

At this point, however, when the type `a` is a `Maybe Type`, I wanted to show the content of the `Wrapper` printing an empty string instead of `Nothing`, or the content of the `Just`; therefore I wrote the `instance Show (Maybe Type)` that I commented above.

Given this, `Type "hello"` and `Just $ Type "hello"` are both correcly shown as `Type`, but `Wrapper $ Just $ Type "hello"` is displayed as `Just Type`, just like it's using `Maybe`'s original instance of `Show`, irrespective of the fact that for this specific type inside the `Maybe` (the `Type`) I've customized the `Show` instance.

Comment: Are you really doing this all from one module? Your behavior sounds a lot like the end of https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap, which describes a pitfall you can encounter if you do this across modules.

Comment: Oh, no, not from one module. I'll clarify this in the question later today (I can't now). For now please, rely on this comment: `Wrapper`, its `Show` instance, `Type`, its `Show` instance, are in 4 separate modules. `instance Show (Maybe Type)` is in the same module as `instance Show Type`.

Comment: Yrks. _Just why?_ All of the things you're attempting here are just a bad idea, IMO.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that does not really help me. Anyway, I tried to strip everything else away from the code, so as to ask one single precise question, and maybe this trivialized it. This evening I'll try to give some background to it.

Comment: Overlapping orphan instances for major Haskell classes (such as `Show`) with major Haskell types (such as `Maybe`) will muck up class resolution for absolutely anyone (transitively) importing your module. This is a real "Don't do that!" sort of situation.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Show` instance declaration for `Wrapper`, we don't really know what `a` is. But apparently we must already choose what `Show` instance to use for the `Maybe a`. With the information available, the only instance that matches is the default one `Show a => Show (Maybe a)`, which doesn't require a concrete `a`.

The GHC User Guide, [in the section about overlapping instances](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=overlappinginstances#overlapping-instances), mentions the concept of "postponing" the choice of an instance:

> That postpones the question of which instance to pick to the call site
> for f by which time more is known about the type b. You can write this
> type signature yourself if you use the FlexibleContexts extension.

and

> Exactly the same situation can arise in instance declarations themselves [...] The solution is to postpone the choice **by adding the constraint to the context of the instance declaration**

We could try such a trick. Instead of requiring `Show a`, require the *whole* `Show (Maybe a)`. Now the `Show` instance is taken as "given" and we don't make a local decision. I think this has the effect of delaying the selection of the `Show (Maybe a)` instance to call sites like `print $ Wrapper $ Just $ Type 3`, where we have more information about the concrete type of `a`.

Testing this hypothesis:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
newtype Type = Type Int

instance Show Type where
  show = const "Type"

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Show (Maybe Type) where
  show (Just t) = show t
  show _ = ""

newtype Wrapper a = Wrapper (Maybe a)

instance Show (Maybe a) => Show (Wrapper a) where
  show (Wrapper edit) = show edit

main :: IO ()
main = print $ Wrapper $ Just $ Type 3
-- output: Type
```

That said, I find this behavior confusing and would steer clear of it in production code.

---

As @dfeuer notes in a comment and linked code, the overlapping instance is problematic. For example, if we add this innocent function to the code of this answer:

```
foo :: Show a => Maybe a -> String
foo = show
```

The module ceases to compile:

```
    * Overlapping instances for Show (Maybe a)
        arising from a use of `show'
      Matching instances:
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance [overlap ok] Show (Maybe Type) -- Defined at Main.hs:14:27
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of `a'
```

But now I'm confused. Why doesn't the exact same type error happen with the instance definition `Show (Wrapper a)` in the original question?

---

The reason `foo` fails to compile seems to be the last bullet point in the description of the instance search procedure:

> Now find all instances, or in-scope given constraints, that **unify with
> the target constraint, but do not match it.** [here, Show (Maybe Type)] Such non-candidate
> instances **might match when the target constraint is further
> instantiated**. If all of them are incoherent top-level instances, the
> search succeeds, returning the prime candidate. Otherwise the search
> fails.
> [...]
>
> The final bullet (about unifiying instances) makes GHC
> conservative about committing to an overlapping instance. For example:
>
> f :: [b] -> [b]
>
> Suppose that from the RHS of f we get the
> constraint C b [b]. But GHC does not commit to instance (C), because
> in a particular call of f, b might be instantiated to Int, in which
> case instance (D) would be more specific still. So GHC rejects the
> program.

Perhaps—unlike normal functions—instance definitions are exempt from this particular rule, but I don't see that mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I would steer clear of it in toy code just for playing too. Sounds awful. And orphan overlapping instances for `base` classes and `base` types? I shudder.

Comment: @dfeuer The instance is overlapping, but not an orphan, at least in the example code. And if one is careful about where `Type` is used, I think it shouldn't interfere with other code too much. I still find the behavior unintuitive though.

Comment: I guess it depends on how strictly you define "orphan". Neither `Show` nor `Maybe` is defined here, and `Maybe` is the outermost constructor. Not sure how it matters where `Type` is used. See [this error](https://tio.run/##LY07D4JAEIT7@xWT2GiBjR3JkVioIfFBhNgvssDF4yCAojH@djwexWZ3Zr/Zzal5sNZ9/3UW0GSyJ2WMvea3ijX7pmnJ3LnBwvkJkVBLiCBtJVyrlzIZwrzshJo5DFcut931uA0C/3wYYxgZLE/0iRnRCl3ONVu7GWw5tTXSgqpxFiItS7juFCNID1OU4HgI29q@HRE54wUpY0VlFy02ff8H).

Comment: @dfeuer You are correct, the instance is quite problematic.

Comment: Why doesn't it happen with the `Show (Wrapper a)`? Who knows? Overlapping instances are horrible. I've read the documentation for them several times and never actually understood what it was saying. The documentation for `INCOHERENT` is just as bad, but I don't think incoherent instances tend to cause as much trouble as long as you follow the rule that you really can't care which one you get.